# Why bool conversion explicitly mentions prvalue

Tags: c++

In 4.14
http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.bool#1

It says:

> A **prvalue** of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a **prvalue** of type bool.

Why specifically emphasize prvalue?

lvalue of arithmetic type can also be converted to bool.

Comment: *lvalue of arithmetic type can also be converted to bool* - Now find out how the standard defines this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't want a boolean conversion to affect lvalues, so it does not allow it.

You can of course convert an lvalue of arithmetic type to type `bool`, but it is not done through (just) a boolean conversion. Converting an arithmetic lvalue into a `bool` is a standard conversion sequence consisting of an *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* followed by a *boolean conversion.*

Comment: do you know the rationale behind "lvalue-to-rvalue" in the case of bool conversion here?

Comment: @FunkyBaby Yes, consistency. All value-related operations in C++ are done on rvalues *only*. When you have `int i = 42; int j = i + 1;`, the `i` will first undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion before `+` sees it, since the operator `+` operates on rvalues. lvalue-to-rvalue conversions happen *all the time* in C++. Why should a boolean conversion be an exception?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But the l/r-value conversion is not mentioned in http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add  . Where is this mentioned?

Comment: @FunkyBaby See [\[expr\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr), especially point 9

Comment: I've already seen it.  That clause doesn't support your claim.